# Handle multiple requests with select

Tags: python, sockets, select

currently I am working on a chat server/client project.
I am struggling with handling multiple requests with select, my server script uses the select module but the client script doesn't. The result is that when ever a user enters message the other clients have to write their own message to read through the conversation. I have searched a lot in the web for examples, but could only find code snippets with sys.stdin which isn't what I want.

I would glad to receive any instruction/explanation.

Server code:

```py
import socket
import select

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 2855))
server_socket.listen(1)

open_client_sockets = [] # current clients handler
messages_to_send = [] # future message send handler

def send_waiting_messages(wlist):
    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        if client_socket in wlist: # if current socket in iteration has reading abilities
            client_socket.send(data)
            messages_to_send.remove(message) # remove from future send handler

def broadcast_message(sock, message):
    for socket in open_client_sockets:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock:
            socket.send(message)

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, []) # apending reading n writing socket to list

    for current_socket in rlist: # sockets that can be read
        if current_socket is server_socket: # if there is a new client
            (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept() 
            open_client_sockets.append(new_socket) # clients list
        else:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024)
            if len(data) == 0:
                open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket) # remove user if he quit.
                print "Connection with client closed."
                send_waiting_messages(wlist) # send message to specfic client
            else:
                broadcast_message(current_socket, "\r" + '<' + data + '> ')

    # send_waiting_messages(wlist) # send message to specfic client

server_socket.close()
```

Client code:

```py
import socket
import msvcrt

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 2855))

data = ""
def read_message():
    msg = ""
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            if key == '\r': # Enter key
                break
            else:
                msg = msg + "" + key

    return msg

while data != "quit":
    data = read_message()
    client_socket.send(data)
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print data
client_socket.close()
```

Comment: This is much harder to accomplish than it looks. Can I suggest you look at twisted? https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: No, I am aware of twisted but I want to implement this in my own. Thank you how ever!

Comment: Why does your client implement `raw_input()` by hand?

Comment: Because raw_input() is a blocking function.

Answer (score 2):

> my server script uses the select module but the client script doesn't.

A solution is to use `select` also in the client. On Windows unfortunately `select` does not handle `sys.stdin`, but we can use the *timeout* argument to poll the keyboard.

```
import socket
import select
import msvcrt
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 2855))
msg = ""
while True:
    ready = select.select([client_socket], [], [], .1)
    if client_socket in ready[0]:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print data, ' '*(len(msg)-len(data))
        print msg,
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getche()
        if key == '\r': # Enter key
            if msg == "quit":
                break
            client_socket.send(msg)
            msg = ""
            print
        else:
            msg = msg + "" + key
client_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are issues on both the server and client side that prevent your application from being truly realtime.  Here are several that I've noticed so far:

1. The client is reading data from the server connection only after writing some data to the socket.  Consider putting the logic to read from the socket into a separate thread.
2. In your server, you iterate across the `rlist` returned by `select()` before sending pending messages to the client; the client fds will only be present in rlist if the client has sent a message.  Sending messages should be done based on writeable fds, by iterating across wlist.  But this has other problems...
3. You always `select()` on writeability for all client fds, even if there's no pending messages to write to that client.  The end result is that your `select()` call will nearly always return immediately, and will waste CPU (which sort of defeats the purpose of select)
4. All your socket IO is done in "blocking" mode, so your `send()` may block if you send more data that the kernel's receive buffer on the remote end can handle (typically this is around 10MB).

You'll be much better off using an asynchronous framework (such as twisted) for implementing this type of application.  Managing all the buffers can be tedious and challenging, and it's work that's already been done before.